# How can I programmatically identify altered frames from a video

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, cryptography

A video can be edit by deleting some frames from it.that can be done by deleting **consecutive frames** or **random frames** in that video.

we need to detect the tampered videos, we hope to do this by detecting frames which has been altered , simply we need to have an algorithm for way to identify deleted frames.Because we are creating a tool which could use for tamper detection as a video surveillance tool.Which could use in law enforcements and courts

Is there any method to identify that frames of a video has been deleted by malicious attacks, there are already available methods such as watermarking, digital signature, but we need an algorithm to detect that frames by using proper algorithm.

Comment: i don't think, that's possible at all.

Comment: this is for my final year project .its for video surveillance tool

Comment: You need to think a bit harder about exactly what you are asking. What is it you are trying to detect? What makes the kind of editing you are looking for the signs of different to the normal editing that goes into making a film? What makes it different to the video content changing suddenly because of something happening in the world in front of the camera, like someone putting their hand over the lens? What is the purpose here? - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: we need to detect the tampering videos, we hope to do this by detecting frames which has been altered , simply we need to have an algorithm for way to identify trimming clips.Because we are creating a tool which could use for tamper detection as a video surveillance tool.Which could use in law enforcements and courts

Comment: The only way to do this reliably is by embedding some metadata in the frames.

Comment: @molbdnilo, exactly. it all boils down to that.

Answer (score 3):

In general, whatever image sequence I am handed, some or all of it could have come from a real camera, from Photoshop or from a 3D renderer, and there is no general purpose image processing technique that will be able to tell the difference based on analysis of the image content alone, either well enough to stand up in court, or, indeed, at all.

You'll need to embed some easy to recognise yet difficult to fake, relocate or tamper with signal into the video at recording time. You've tagged the question "opencv", but the fields you want to investigate are cryptography and watermarking, not computer vision.

Have the video surveillance equipment use public key crypto to visibly watermark each frame with an identifier unique to the piece of equipment, a timestamp, a frame sequence number and a hash or other suitable function of the frame image, using a scheme robust to compression.

Tampering with the video sequence will then require either knowledge of the device's private key, or removal of the watermark. This isn't great (keeping the private key secret will be a logistical headache) but is probably the best solution you can get.

Answer (score 1):

this can't be done in general. However some approaches may be possible.

- the used video format may support frame wise meta data that stores the index or time index and that is not touched during editing
- the image sensor itself may be configured to write some meta data to some specific region of the image
- you may have some external reference that was imaged by the camera and may help identify missing frames

  - precise clock
  - fast blinking indicator
  - some uniform motion